# Resize LUKS Partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, luks, fdisk, parted

I have a 68 GB logical LUKS partition at the very end of a drive, and to the left of that I have 60 GB of free unallocated space. Both of these partitions together make up an extended partition.

I spent a lot of time freeing this unallocated space, moving it into this extended partition so it could be next to the LUKS partition, which I have also decrypted with `cryptsetup`.

When I try using gparted or kde-partitionmanager to expand the LUKS partition into this free space I am unable to drag it to the left, in gparted it appears the extended partition has them both separated in individual cells, only able to move it to the right.

Any one have any ideas for adding that extra 60 GB? How should I go about moving the LUKS partition to the left, so that the unallocated space goes to the right of it, so that I can finish by just resize/dragging the border of the LUKS partition to the right.

Gparted image of my partitions:

[image: Gparted image of my partitions]

Comment: Did you try it with the luks device unopened (still encrypted)? You should be able to drag the partition as long as it is unopened.

Comment: Was not able to resize/move luks partition or drag it via gparted. Only able to do it after decrypting it.